# Nginx: proxy_pass dynamic from location

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, proxypass, dynamic

I hope you can help me with a little but tricky nginx problem:

I want to configure a dynamic location-block like this:

```
location /test1/* {  
    proxy_pass destination.com/api/*;  
    proxy_buffering off;  
}
```

If the URL is `.../test1/folder1` the request should be passed to `destination.com/api/folder1`

I've tried it already with the variable `$request_uri` `proxy_pass destination.com/api/$request_uri;` - it didn't work for me.

EDIT:
The site "/test1/" itself should NOT be redirected - only the part after "/test1/". How is that possible?

UPDATE 11.02.2016: Still no solution :(

Thanks for your help/answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a simple solution.
3 location blocks:

> location = /test1/  --> stay local
>                proxy_pass  local-upstream$request_uri;
>                rewrite ^(.*)    localdomain;
>
> location = /test1   --> stay local
>               proxy_pass  local-upstream$request_uri;
>               rewrite ^(.*)    localdomain;
>
> location /test1/ {
>   proxy_pass destination.com/api/;
>   }

The upstream is defined in the main config file:

> upstream local-upstream {
>           server ip-address;
>   }

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the URI before pass it to the server like this:

```
location /test1/ {
    proxy_set_header    Host destination.com;
    proxy_redirect http://destination.com/api/ http://$http_host/test1/;
    rewrite ^/test1/(.*)$ /api/$1 break;
    proxy_pass destination.com;
}
```

Hope this help.

**Update:** Add proxy_set_header to change Host to correct domain name. Also add proxy_redirect to correct the Location in response header if needed.

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't help. The "destination" is a remote system. The path does not exist on the local nginx system.

Comment: Which path did you mean here? For a remote system with different domain, let's add some config as I edited.

Comment: This looks good and seems to work, BUT "/test1/" itself should NOT be redirected - only the part after "/test1/". How is that possible?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but hope this help. In your case, let's change 4th line to:
`rewrite ^/test1/(.+)$ /api/$1 break;`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `*` in `location`. And you must have protocol in `proxy_pass`.
This should work:

```
location /test1/ {  
    proxy_pass http://destination.com/api/;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```